# using bash how can i get the network device name and ip address in one line?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I want to get the Network Interface device name (ens###) along with its associated IP address (###.###.###.###).  I have solutions to get one or the other but I have not been able to find something that can output each pair (Name + IP) to a line.

Here is a command to get IP

```
ip address | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1'
```

And here I can get the device name

```
ip address | grep -v lo | cut -d ' ' -f2 | tr ':' '\n' | awk NF
```

However I would like a way to get both which would output each set to their own line, something like this

```
ens32 10.0.0.100
ens33 10.1.0.100
```

EDIT:

Here is a sample output of ip address

```
[root@centos ~]# ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens32: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.100/23 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global dynamic ens32
       valid_lft 83040sec preferred_lft 83040sec
    inet6 0000::000:0000:0000:0000/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.0.100/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic ens33
       valid_lft 1277sec preferred_lft 1277sec
    inet6 0000::000:0000:0000:0000/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

SOLUTIONS:

Both of these will give me the same desired output.  Thanks for the help!

```
ip -o addr show scope global | awk '/^[0-9]:/{print $2, $4}' | cut -f1 -d '/'
ip -o addr show scope global | tr -s ' ' | tr '/' ' ' | cut -f 2,4 -d ' '
```

Comment: @EdMorton apologize, I have added the sample output here

Comment: If you start with ```ip -4 addr show scope global``` you'll eliminate the ```lo``` interface without needing ```grep -v```.

Comment: Using the `-o` argument, as in `ip -o addr list`, will give you a much easier starting place, *already* putting each address on only one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a one-liner, try this (thanks to Dougie for the more refined `ip` command) :

```
ip -oneline -4 addr show scope global | tr -s ' ' | tr '/' ' ' | cut -f 2,4 -d ' '
```

`-oneline` forces output for each interface to a single line.

Then we `cut` out just the interface name and IP from the output, `tr`anslating it a bit along the way (for cut to get rid of extra stuff).

Answer (score 3):

Well, `awk`, as always, works like a charm.

```
ip address | 
awk '
    /^[0-9]:/{
        name=substr($2, 1, length($2) - 1)
    }
    /^[ ]*inet /{
        split($2, a, "/")
        if (name != "lo")
            print name,a[1]
    }
'
```

will ouptut:

```
ens32 10.0.0.100
ens33 10.1.0.100
```

1. If the line starts with a number and doublescore, then get the name from the second field except remove the `:` with substr.
2. If the line starts with inet and spaces, that means that the second arg has the ip address. I also remove the netmask suffix with a simple split.
3. If the interface name is `lo` we don't print the output, thus filtering loopback interface.

Comment: Setting a field separator can simplify things: `awk -F'[ :/]+' '/^[0-9]+:/ {name = $2} $2 == "inet" && name != "lo" {print name, $3}'`